# Umbraco index says data is one thing, but umbracoHelper methods return another thing

Tags: c#, umbraco

My index states that some documents have a sort order as expected, but when pulling data out of the database using:

`umbracoHelper.TypedContentAtRoot()`, the sort order is incorrect.

It's like something hasn't updated correctly when publishing the sort order?

I did somehow manage to budge it the other day but i do not know what made it happen.

Any ideas why this is?

**Edit:**

I have noticed that locally it seems to respect the sort order correctly but on the Azure server i'm hosting the web app on, the order is wrong.

**Edit:**

The umbraco.config on the server is not being updated for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

I had to right click on "Content" and Republish entire site. Publishing my own custom content again did not re-build the umbraco.config